# Estimation of bivariate function with one variable being constricted

Tags: nonparametric, kernel-trick, bivariate, nonparametric-regression

Suppose the following classical supervised regression setting,
$$y_{i} = f(x_{i}) + \epsilon_{i}, \quad i=1,\cdots,n,$$
where $\epsilon_{i}$ are i.i.d. zero mean Gaussian noise.

The above regression problem can be solved by classical non-parametric approaches, e.g. kernel method.

However, if I suppose that I have a pre-determined (or pre-trained) model $h(x)$, such that
$$f(x) = g(x,h(x)).$$
Here, the $g$ is a bivariate function but with the second coordinate restricted in the form of $h(x)$.

When none of the variables is restricted, one can apply the kernel method (like kernel ridge regression) to obtain the estimate $\hat{g}$ in the tensor space of the RKHS. However, I'm wondering if there is any existing literature/research for estimating $g$ given $g$ in such a restricted form.

Comment: Is there some restriction on $g$? If it's unrestricted, I don't see how learning $g(x, h(x))$ is any different than learning $f(x)$. Or is the function supposed to be $g(x_1, h(x_2))$?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. 

No further restrictions. The general idea is that if $h(x)$ is similar to $f(x)$, then incorporating a learned $h(x)$ in estimating $f(x)$ (thus $g(x,h(x))$) will be better than directly learning $f(x)$ in terms of convergence rate, etc. This is the reason I impose the relationship $f(x) = g(x,h(x))$. There are solutions when $g(x,h(x))$ takes some specific form like additive form. However, here I'm targeting a more general $g(x,h(x))$ which I don't specify its form but a general function (maybe in some functional space like RKHS)  induced by $h(x)$.

Comment: Without further restrictions on the relation between $g$ and $h$, I don't see how this could be different than just learning $g(x)$ directly?